# Log of cron actions on OS X

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, cron

Does the cron which comes with OS X log its actions anywhere?

I'm not looking for output of any particular cron job, but rather log of what cron is doing. On a couple linux machines I've checked, there's `/var/log/cron` which has contents like:

```
Apr 26 11:00:01 localhost crond[27755]: (root) CMD (/root/bin/mysql-backup)
Apr 26 11:01:01 localhost crond[27892]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Apr 26 11:07:01 localhost crond[28138]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/bin/python /home/
user1/scripts/pythonscript.py)
Apr 26 11:18:18 localhost crontab[28921]: (user2) LIST (user2)
Apr 26 11:18:22 localhost crontab[28929]: (user2) BEGIN EDIT (user2)
Apr 26 11:18:59 localhost crontab[28929]: (user2) REPLACE (user2)
```

This shows when jobs ran, when users viewed or edited crontabs, etc. This stuff is nowhere that I've  found on my Snow Leopard machine.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Much easier to simply add the following to /etc/syslog.conf :

```
cron.*      /var/log/cron.log
```

Then restart syslog

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist
```

Tested and working on OSX 10.7.4

Comment: Wow, much simpler. Have an upvote. I wonder if this would've worked on  Snow Leopard.

Comment: Works on Mavericks

Comment: Works on Yosemite

Comment: Works on Snow Leopard, 10.6.8 (yes, I'm an antique...)

Comment: Works on El Capitan

Comment: /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged 
(10.13.2 High Sierra).  
Do I have to disable SIP? Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I figured it how to log my cron job activity without switching each one over to launchd jobs.

The [cron man page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/cron.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/cron) mentions `-x` options which enables "writing of debugging information to standard output." A side effect of this is that these also write basic information to standard error. Data sent to standard error is written to `/var/log/system.log`.

This results in data like this being written to `/var/log/system.log`:

```
debug flags enabled: misc
[42073] cron started
log_it: (user1 42084) CMD (/root/bin/mysql-backup)
log_it: (user1 42094) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Since cron itself is launched by launchd, to enable this, I had to edit `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.vix.cron.plist` so that it now looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.vix.cron</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/sbin/cron</string>
        <string>-x</string>
        <string>misc</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PathState</key>
        <dict>
            <key>/etc/crontab</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>QueueDirectories</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/lib/cron/tabs</string>
    </array>
    <key>EnableTransactions</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/cron.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I used `-x misc` here, but it didn't seem to matter which options I used. Adding the `-x` started the logging of job activity. I also added the StandardErrorPath to write to `/var/log/cron.log` instead of the default `/var/log/system.log`.

And then unload and reload this:

```
$ sudo launchctl
Password:
launchd% unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.vix.cron.plist 
launchd% load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.vix.cron.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

OSX now tends to use launchd rather than cron -  [Apple dev doc](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/Daemons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001761-SW1) - so it might be there is nothing in cron to log.

Use launchctl to control the logging level of launchd. Som log info appears in system.log but more in the console app -> All messages

Comment: Hmmm, switching to launchd is something I could consider, but I'm a grumpy old unix user. I followed that link. The example on that page is 1046 bytes long to replace 24 characters of crontab `0 0 7 11 0 happybirthday`.

Answer (score 0):

At least on Yosemite, cron logs output as `mail` messages, so use the `mail` to read them.

Comment: `cron` sends (otherwise un-redirected) output to the owner of the job via mail.  If all output is redirected, no mail is sent.  (Even if a message is sent, I'm not sure whether it shows the command that was executed.)  The question is asking how the administrator can see all the commands that `cron` has performed.  To use your answer, a person would have to look at everybody's mail file.