# where is cron activity logged on OSX?

Tags: macos, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Log of cron actions on OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/134864/log-of-cron-actions-on-os-x)

on SuSe in '/var/log/messages' I can read `Jan 27 09:50:01 firebird /usr/sbin/cron[4004]: (root) CMD (/srv/www/htdocs/imacs ....`

Is there any equivalent on OSX 10.6.2?

Couldn't find anything in Console Utility. `man cron` didn't help either...