# crontab setup on Mac

Tags: mac, crontab

I'm trying to setup a crontab on the Mac. It just simply prints the message "Hello there!" to the console at a specific time, but it doesn't seem to work. Below is what I have in the crontab:

```
28 16 * * * echo "Hello there!"
```

Nothing happened at 4:28 pm. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Cronjob does not output to screen or any terminal. On a default installation the cron jobs get logged to

```
/var/log/syslog
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. Where can I locate that /var/log/syslog location from the root? Sorry, I'm a noob in Mac

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/134864/log-of-cron-actions-on-os-x

Comment: I checked my system.log file, but I didn't see any update today.

Comment: OS X's cron doesn't log output to either /var/log/syslog or /var/log/system.log by default. The question linked above describes how to enable logging by modifying com.vix.cron.plist.