# Can I use cron or launchd to run a bash script without being logged in?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, cron, launchd

I'd like to have a simple bash script run (regardless of whether anyone is logged in or not) akin to putting it in `/etc/cron.daily/` on Linux, but on Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.4. If it's possible, how? All it needs to do is copy (and maybe `bzip`) a file.

Comment: cron should run without being logged in. cron works the same way anywhere.

Comment: Try a `crontab -e`. Create a job to touch a file in in a few minutes. Log out. Wait those minutes. Check if the file has been created.  (Optionally: remove the now useless cron job :) )

Comment: you don't have to be logged in but the computer does need to be in the active mode, meaning not closed

Answer (score 0):

Using cron, you can edit the superuser's crontab with for example `EDITOR=nano sudo crontab -e`. When I tried adding a line like `* * * * * say aa`, the say command was run even after I logged out to the login window.

Using launchd, save a property list like this as for example `/Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>test</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>say</string>
    <string>bb</string>
  </array>
  <key>StartInterval</key>
  <integer>10</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then run `sudo chown root /Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist` and `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist`. The say command scheduled by launchd was also run when I logged out to the login window.

Comment: If I set the script to run while I'm logged in, it seems to work, but not when I'm logged out. Also, I can't find any entry in the log for it to see what went wrong.

Comment: Both methods worked for me when I tried logging out to the login window. If you mean the cron log, you can enable logging by [editing com.vix.cron.plist](http://superuser.com/questions/134864/log-of-cron-actions-on-os-x/135262#135262). If you mean launchd, you can save the stderr or stdout of the program to a log file by adding a StandardErrorPath or StandardOutPath key. See `man launchd.plist`.

Answer (score 0):

Cron is officially deprecated, so you should use launchd.

There is a tutorial at apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html

A good starting point for explaining where to put the plist file

https://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/mac-osx-startup-crontab-launchd-jobs

A bit more details can be found at

http://www.launchd.info

Two things that got/confused me:

1) Pay attention between the difference between Program and ProgramArgments

2) If the job you want to run is a script, it needs to have the `#!/bin/sh`, otherwise launchd cannot start it, and you will end up with a confusing exit/status-code 78.